# Проблема с пустым пространством между виджетами в QGridLayout

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Здравствуйте. Изучаю Qt и столкнулся с довольной абсурдной проблемой, никак не могу расставить виджеты в QGridLayout так, что между двумя лайнами(слева на фото)  не возникала огромная пропасть. У аналогичной пары лайнов справа подобной проблемы нет. Дефект появляется как только начинаю добавлять виджеты на (x, 1) позицию в нижних слоях. Пробовал экспериментировать со span-ами, получается полная мешанина. Пытался добавить виджеты сначала в дочерний layout, а затем его  в грид, опять же хуже, чем было изначально. В общем, на первый взгляд ерундовая проблема, но я уже второй день с ней ковыряюсь.

[интерфейс http://s35-temporary-files.radikal.ru/905f014fe8354939899bd39e17b2ea44/-88693455.jpg](http://s35-temporary-files.radikal.ru/905f014fe8354939899bd39e17b2ea44/-88693455.jpg)

Вот код, который отвечает за это окно:

```
controlScreen = new QWidget;

controlScreen->setFixedSize(530, 234);
controlScreen->setStyleSheet("background-color:black;");

secondWLayout = new QGridLayout;

idSwapLabel = new QLabel("Swap place.");
fromLabel = new QLabel("Swap id from:");
fromLabel->setFixedSize(81, 21);

toLabel = new QLabel("to:");
toLabel->setFixedSize(31, 21);

oldIdLine = new QLineEdit;
oldIdLine->setFixedSize(31, 21);
newIdLine = new QLineEdit;
newIdLine->setFixedSize(31, 21);

oldLine = new QLineEdit;
oldLine->setReadOnly(true);
oldLine->setFixedSize(111, 21);
newLine = new QLineEdit;
newLine->setReadOnly(true);
newLine->setFixedSize(111, 21);

orderButton = new QPushButton("swap");
orderButton->setFixedSize(91, 21);

deleteLabel = new QLabel("Delete:");
deleteLabel->setFixedSize(71, 21);

deleteLine = new QLineEdit();
deleteLine->setFixedSize(141, 21);

deleteButton = new QPushButton("Delete");
deleteButton->setFixedSize(91, 21);

secondWLayout->addWidget(fromLabel, 0, 0);
secondWLayout->addWidget(oldIdLine, 0, 1);
secondWLayout->addWidget(oldLine, 0, 2);
secondWLayout->addWidget(toLabel, 0, 3);
secondWLayout->addWidget(newIdLine, 0, 4);
secondWLayout->addWidget(newLine, 0, 5);
secondWLayout->addWidget(orderButton, 1, 1);
secondWLayout->addWidget(deleteLabel, 2, 0);
secondWLayout->addWidget(deleteLine, 2, 1);
secondWLayout->addWidget(deleteButton, 3, 1);

controlScreen->setLayout(secondWLayout);

controlScreen->setWindowModality(Qt::ApplicationModal);
controlScreen->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
controlScreen->show();
```

Comment: Попробуйте создать форму в дизайнере форм и с нею играться, пока не будет полностью устраивать, и если тогда останется желание форму в коде описать, смотрите сгенерированную форму в папке build. Для `form.ui` сгенерированным будет файл `ui_form.h`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
secondWLayout->addWidget(fromLabel, 0, 0);
secondWLayout->addWidget(oldIdLine, 0, 1);
secondWLayout->addWidget(oldLine, 0, 2);
secondWLayout->addWidget(toLabel, 0, 3);
secondWLayout->addWidget(newIdLine, 0, 4);
secondWLayout->addWidget(newLine, 0, 5);
secondWLayout->addWidget(orderButton, 1, 1, 1, 2);
secondWLayout->addWidget(deleteLabel, 2, 0);
secondWLayout->addWidget(deleteLine, 2, 1, 1, 2);
secondWLayout->addWidget(deleteButton, 3, 1, 1, 2);
```

Получается такое:

[image: gridlayout]